# Extract from array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array :

```
$dish = [
    'fr' => [
            ['lunch','starter','dish name fr 1','dish info 1','price 1'],
            ['lunch','starter','dish name fr 2','dish info 2','price 2'],
            ['both','starter','dish name fr 3','dish info 3','price 3'],
            ['both','main','dish name fr 4','dish info 4','price 4'],
            ['both','main','dish name fr 5','dish info 5','price 5'],
            ['both','main','dish name fr 6','dish info 6','price 6'],
            ['both','dessert','dish name fr 7','dish info 7','price 7'],
            ['diner','dessert','dish name fr 8','dish info 8','price 8'],
            ],
    'nl' => [
            ['lunch','starter','dish name nl 1','dish info 1','price 1'],
            ['lunch','starter','dish name nl 2','dish info 2','price 2'],
            ['both','starter','dish name nl 3','dish info 3','price 3'],
            ['both','main','dish name nl 4','dish info 4','price 4'],
            ['both','main','dish name nl 5','dish info 5','price 5'],
            ['both','main','dish name nl 6','dish info 6','price 6'],
            ['both','dessert','dish name nl 7','dish info 7','price 7'],
            ['diner','dessert','dish name nl 8','dish info 8','price 8'],
            ],
    'en' => [
            ['lunch','starter','dish name en 1','dish info 1','price 1'],
            ['lunch','starter','dish name en 2','dish info 2','price 2'],
            ['both','starter','dish name en 3','dish info 3','price 3'],
            ['both','main','dish name en 4','dish info 4','price 4'],
            ['both','main','dish name en 5','dish info 5','price 5'],
            ['both','main','dish name en 6','dish info 6','price 6'],
            ['both','dessert','dish name en 7','dish info 7','price 7'],
            ['diner','dessert','dish name en 8','dish info 8','price 8'],
            ],
];
```

with

```
foreach ($dish[$lang] as list($a, $b, $dish_name, $dish_info, $price)) {  
echo $dish_name 
; }
```

I managed to have by languages:

> dish name fr 1
>
> dish name fr 2
>
> dish name fr 3
>
> dish name nl 1
>
> dish name nl 2
>
> dish name nl 3
>
> dish name en 1
>
> dish name en 2
>
> dish name en 3

but I also would like to display by dishes:

> **Starter**
>
> dish name fr 1
>
> dish name nl 1
>
> dish name en 1
>
> dish name fr 2
>
> dish name nl 2
>
> dish name en 2
>
> dish name fr 3
>
> dish name nl 3
>
> dish name en 3
>
> **Main**
>
> dish name fr 4
>
> dish name nl 4
>
> dish name en 4
>
> dish name fr 5
>
> dish name nl 5
>
> dish name en 5
>
> dish name fr 3
>
> dish name nl 3
>
> dish name en 3

How would you do?

Thank you

Comment: Well, it depends on whether you can or cannot to change the format of input array. If you can, I'd suggest to make it more flexible - to take from it anything you need without having all the dishes types mixed. so, I'd change the structure of incoming array.

Comment: if the format is same you can consider using `array_column()` .That will help you to skip the loop, if you can use it well.

Answer (score 0):

I would properly rebuild it into another array like so:

```
$newArr = array();

$i = 0;
foreach($dish AS $langString => $lang){
    foreach($lang AS $key => $subdish){
        $newArr[$subdish[1]][$i]['dish'] = $subdish[2];
        $newArr[$subdish[1]][$i]['sort'] = $key;
        $i++;
    }
}

function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['sort'] - $b['sort'];
}

usort($newArr['starter'], 'sortByOrder');
usort($newArr['main'], 'sortByOrder');
usort($newArr['dessert'], 'sortByOrder');

foreach($newArr as $course => $food){

    echo '<h2>' . $course .'</h2>';
    foreach($food as $plate){
        echo $plate['dish'] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that it could properly be done smarter and more efficient, this is just purely to give you an' idea of how you could achieve something like this.

Also, you'd have to find a way to sort the dishes in the new array so they are ordered the way you desire.

**Update**

Added sort functionality, yes there is a lot of code for something supposedly simple, but this was what I could brew up at the time and with the data structure available.

Comment: thank you for your help!
It gives me dishes by type (starter, main and dessert), how can I sort them to have by language:
dish 1 fr
dish 1 nl
dish 1 en

Dish 2 fr
...

Comment: @MrViny See my updated answer, it now sorts as you want it to, copy the entire code as there are some fundamental changes. Please remember to accept my answer if it works out for you :)